# I cannot seem to find how to add SoundPool to my specific game

Tags: java, android, soundpool

So I'm new to java and have a game that has as it's main activity a class called "Game" which extends Activity, a "MainThread" and a GamePanel class that extends SurfaceView
http://blog.ashwanik.in/2014/12/play-sounds-in-android-application.html

```
  SoundPoolManager.CreateInstance();
  List<integer> sounds = new ArrayList<integer>();
  sounds.add(R.raw.first);
  sounds.add(R.raw.second);
  sounds.add(R.raw.third);
  SoundPoolManager.getInstance().setSounds(sounds);
  try {
    SoundPoolManager.getInstance().InitializeSoundPool(this, new ISoundPoolLoaded() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
    }
});
 } catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem is that when i add that code from above into either the Game class (main) or GamePanel (which has most of the code in the game) it doesn't give me an error or anything it simply doesn't play the sound, most of the tutorials on this have explanations on how to do it with buttons but i can't seem to find it on how to get it playing on an actual game